# AR model initial parameters

Tags: autoregressive

This is a very basic question, but for whatever reason I haven't been able to find an explanation for it. When we have an AR(M) model for some model order M, where (for M=2, as an example) y(n) = a1*y(n-1) + a2*y(n-2) + w(n), what are the initial values of y(n-1) and y(n-2) at time n=0? Are they just set to zero, or what? Or are they undefined (since time would be negative) for n=0, but set to zero for n=1 and n=2, respectively? Or is there some other convention that is used? All the sources I've seen just describe the basic relationship without actually explaining what the very first recorded values of "y" would contain from y(0), y(1), etc. Any advice would be very much appreciated.